# Accessing inner method in python from another method

Tags: python

I am trying to access inner method in python from another method but on doing this it is giving me "AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'b'"

My Scenario is:

```
class Foo:
    def first_method(self):
        something
        def test(self):
           print 'Hi'

    def second_method(self):
       a = self.test()
```

The line `a = self.test()` is throwing an error.

Comment: If you want `test()` to be a normal method of `Foo`, is there any reason you are not defining `test()` as a normal method of `Foo`, but rather as a local function inside `first_method()`?

Comment: You can't. Why do you want this?

Answer (score 6):

The function `test` is only available in the local scope of `first_method`. If you want to access it in other functions you will have to retain a reference to it somewhere. Something like the following will work:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def first_method(self):
...         def test():
...            print 'Hi'
...         self.test = test
...     def second_method(self):
...         self.test()
... 
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.second_method()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in second_method
AttributeError: Foo instance has no attribute 'test'
>>> f.first_method()
>>> f.second_method()
Hi
```

Notice that there are a few changes to the question in the code. For example, the function `test` takes no arguments. Also note that `first_method` must be called before `second_method`.

Comment: Note that functions assigned to instance attributes are not methods; they do not have access to the instance when called, i.e. they won't get passed `self`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach they won't get passed `self`, but as in this code, that doesn't mean they don't have access to it (thanks to closure semantics). Also, that problem is solveable in other contexts by doing `self.test = types.MethodType(test, self)`.

Comment: @lvc: Completely agreed.  I just thought this is an issue to be aware of, in particular since the OP used an explicit `self` parameter for the local function `test()`.